# Delphi: How do I get a stack trace from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging

I use `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` to debug exceptions raised in the main thread of my app when it works on a client's PC. It gives only adresses but its quite enough to locale most problems except when the main thread is frozen.

For this kind of bug I made a watchdog thread like this

```
procedure TWatchDog.Execute;
var
  res:  NativeInt;
begin
  repeat
    If not Terminated then sleep(1000);
    res:=SendMessageTimeout(MainFormHandle,WM_NULL,0,0,SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG,10000,nil);
    If (res=0) and (HangsReported<4) then begin
      WasHanged:=true;
      APIs.SendMessage('WatchDog *HANG DETECTED* (v.'+Version_Num+') codes: '+ GenCRushRep);
      inc(HangsReported);
    end;
  until Terminated;
end;
```

The function `GenCRushRep` returns last 16 stack frames given by `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` but it contains nothing helpful about the situation caused the main thread to hang.

Is there any way to collect some more useful info from the main thread in a watchdog thread?

Comment: `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace()` can't capture a stack trace across thread boundaries, it captures the stack of the calling thread only. You will have to use another API that allows you to specify the target thread to capture, such as `StackWalk64()`. You will also have to suspect/resume that thread while capturing it

Comment: JclDebug can do this. Read that code to find out how.